# how to solve mismatched type error in substrate?

Tags: rpc, substrate-node, evm, blockchain, service

I have been  integrating paritytech frontier(0.9.43) version with the substrate 0.9.43 version .   while integrating when i added frontier changes in rpc.rs and service.rs file i am facing this error. can  you  tell how to solve these.[image]